# Can a memory leak affect a while loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program for university that when the user enters the number 1, a new node is created in a linked list with the data being an object for another class and if they input 5 they can exit the program. However, in my tests when I go to create a second node the loop to add it to the list seems to fail. This is shown by the program not doing anything after I try to create the second node. I believe it's a memory leak or a problem with pointers and references as the loop eliminating the loop just gives a segmentation error. For ex: The first node will be created but when inputting the second node's data it doesn't accept the input. I input 4, enter, nothing happens except terminal moves to new line even when removing the delete.

```
cout << "Please enter the student's number: " << endl;
        cin >> number;
        student* s = new student;
        s = new student(name, department, number);
        list.addNode(*s);
        cout << "There are now " << list.countNodes() << " nodes." << endl;
```

list.cpp:

```
void list::addNode(students::student& s)
  {
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->setData(s);
    temp->setNext(nullptr);
    node* copy = headPtr;

    if (copy == nullptr)
    {
      headPtr = temp;
    }
    else
    {
      while (copy->getNext() == nullptr)
      {
        copy = copy->getNext();
      }
      copy->setNext(temp);
    }
    delete temp;
  }
```

Comment: That I had to expend considerable effort to scroll down here and add a comment is a sign this is *way too much code*. Please, trim it down to the part that has a problem. Create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You're using `new` and then slamming in a de-referenced pointer? Why? Just `emplace_back` and do it in one shot, *no pointers*. If your Node thing, which I presume is part of the assignment, needs to import student records, use a regular local variable and just deal with the copying cost.

Comment: Maybe you can't use `std::vector` or `std::list` in your final project, but you can at least test with it to see if that `list` thing you've cooked up is problematic or not. Tip: When working on non-trivial code bases it always helps to use unit tests, like with [catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2), to build confidence in your components before assembling them into the complete program.

Comment: Tip: Get rid of `using namespace std` *especially* when using names like `list` which conflict with `std::list`.

Comment: When we ask for a [mre] it's not entirely because we're lazy and can't be bothered to look over what is referred to in common parlance as "A <expletive deleted> of a lot of code."  it's because MRE is a powerful debugging technique. More often than not you only get part way into making the MRE  before the noise around the bug is reduced to the point that the bug becomes obvious. After that, you either fix the bug and don't ask a question at all or you keep going and present the finished MRE in the question to see if anyone has a solution or slick work-around.

Comment: To answer the title of your question:  Yes, memory leaks can affect `while` loops.  For example, if memory is always allocated inside the loop but never deallocated, you could run out of memory; which affects the loop and the entire program.

Comment: *"I believe it's a memory leak"* -- a memory leak would not cause a failure to add a node to a list. Please focus on a specific symptom. Perhaps add two nodes to your list then perform some output that demonstrates the failure. Speculation is not bad, but put your objective observations first. (If your speculation was on-target, you would not be asking this question.)

Comment: *"that when the user enters the number 1"* -- this is completely unnecessary *for this question*. It is probably needed for your assignment, but we're not grading that. Get rid of all user input. Simply do what needs to be done to demonstrate the error (**minimal**). At the same time, keep your code **complete**. Do have your "driver" code in an actual `main()` function. Someone considering helping should be able to copy the example code from this question, paste it into a file or an online compiler, and reproduce your symptoms (not having to supply user input makes this process easier.)

Answer (score 1):

First problem I saw:

```
void list::addNode(students::student& s)
{
```

...

```
    copy->setNext(temp);
    }
delete temp;
}
```

After setting `next` to `temp`, you delete `temp`.

UB right there. Next time you'll try to use this object, you'll try to access deleted memory.